# How to display multiple loops for same content type?

Tags: views, nodes, theming

I have a content type called "Principle". I have 15 Principles and for front-end reasons I need to display them using 5 loops, each loop should print 3 principles. Each loop will print a row. For that I have created a field called field_row_number.

What's the best way to achieve this? I have tried Views with blocks but that only prints the 15 principles as a list.

I need to be able to add all the CSS classes I need to the HTML. So the generated markup would be something like this:

```
<!-- grid simplified example -->
<div class="principles-row">
<!-- here we print 3 principles (in this case 3, 4 and 5) -->
  <ul class="principles-ul">
    <li>Principle 3</li>    
    <li>Principle 4</li>    
    <li>Principle 5</li>    
  </ul>
  <div class="details-box">
    <div class="detail-box">details for Principle 3 go here</div>
    <div class="detail-box">details for Principle 4 go here</div>
    <div class="detail-box">details for Principle 5 go here</div>
 </div>
```

I need to generate the above structure 5 times using field_row_number.

I'm fairly new to Drupal. Any suggestions?

Comment: In Views `Format: Grid` will help you set the number of columns..